# How can I call to function that exists in other file?

Tags: c

Given 2 files, for examples:

file1.c :

```
int main(){
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

file2.c:

```
void f(){
  return;
}
```

Why I can't call `f` from `file1.c` like that?

Answer (score 3):

Because first you need to tell the compiler (**declare**) that it exists somewhere:

```
void f(); //function declaration

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Usually, though, it is better to put such declarations in a separate header file (e.g. `file2.h`) so that later you could include this file (e.g. `#include "file2.h"`) instead of duplicating such declaration in every other file where you need this function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that file1.c does not "know" that the function f exists. You need to use a prototype. The standard way is to put prototypes in header files and definitions in .c files.

It could look like this:

file1.c:

```
#include "file2.h"
int main(){
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

file2.h:

```
#ifndef FILE2_H
#define FILE2_H
void f();
#endif
```

file2.c:

```
#include "file2.h"
void f(){
    return;
}
```

Comment: @PeterJ_01 You're right. I removed everything about it.